# How to close-without-save an Excel /xlsm workbook, w/ a custom function, from C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an Excel workbook with a custom non-time-dependent cell function that I am opening from a C# WindowsForms application using Interop.Excel. I read four values from it, perform no explicit changes/calculations, then close it from C#.

When I try to directly close (without saving), I get a save prompt. I suspect this is because Excel is interpreting auto-recalculation on open as creating a change, even though nothing actually numerically or formulaically changes. I also set `Excel.Application.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual`. How do I prevent the save prompt from appearing and just close-without-save?

Comment: you can also do a `workbook.Saved = true` before saving to let excel app know that this is already saved and no need to prompt..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When you use the Excel objects, be sure to close the workbook like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("Yourworkbook");

xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

....do your stuff

xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);

xlApp.Quit();
```

The false in the close method indicates don't save changes.

Comment: Is it truly necessary to pass the `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` arguments to the `Close` method? I'm closing by only passing false, and haven't had any problems yet.

Comment: @JeremyCook
Once upon a time it was, maybe the need to do so changed with a dot net update.

Comment: It is no longer necessary to pass the `Missing.Value`. With support for [named and optional arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) introduced in C# 4.0, you can just write `xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges: false);`

Comment: What if I want to close the worksheet after saving it ? I don't want SaveAs dialog to be displayed as well. Force save kind of thing ?

Comment: @John
Really a different question, but do something like this before `xlWorkBook.Close` : `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` 
`xlWorkBook.SaveAs (etc.)`
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: @Motes This saves multiple copies... My workbook is referenced and edited a number times. Is it possible to overwrite the existing one ?

Comment: @John
Specify file name

Comment: Ahh!!! My mistake. I don't want to overwrite. Instead add the new data to existing file (Keeping the old data safe)

Comment: @John
You need to ask a new question, please.